# Lighttpd vhost config

Tags: debian, lighttpd

I am running lighttpd on Debian.  Is there a way I can place my virtual host designations outside of the /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf file?  I want to try for a cleaner approach, as my file is getting a bit long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split lighttpd vhost on multiple file as in apache..

For example you want to add two vhost configuration in two separate file, first you need to include this file in default /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf :

1)At the bottom of the file, add:

`include "domain1.com.conf"`

`include "domain2.net.conf"`

2)Open /etc/lighttpd/domain1.com.conf file:

`vi /etc/lighttpd/domain1.com.conf`

Add following configuration directive:

`$HTTP["host"] =~ "domain1\.com" {
            server.document-root = "/dir/to/www"
            accesslog.filename         = "/dir/to/logs/access.log"
}`

Save and close the file.

repeat the same action for other domain2.net.conf, and so on ...